# In Ib, how do I prevent Mary from killing Garry?

Tags: ib

I'm currently in the Sketchbook section, where you find the Toy Box. What happens there is that Mary pushes you in, follows you and steals Ib's rose. Then, invariably, this takes place:

[image: noooo Garry why]

Predictably, the crazy broad then kills Garry by plucking his spirit rose. I guess that's what being imaginary does to you.

So, is there any way to save Garry and stop this from happening? There doesn't seem to be anything to do in the Toy Box except triggering this scene, and my limited dialog options don't seem to make a blind bit of difference either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The game uses an internal variable called GarryDeathCount (presumably short for Garry Death Counter) to determine whether Garry will be slain near the end of the game. Some people prefer to think of it as Mary's Hate or Damage to the Exhibits. If the counter reaches 3, Ib's Rose will not appear in the toy box and Garry will be doomed.

Unless noted, these raise the counter by 1. To avoid Garry's demise, you'll want to avoid doing these:

- Allow Garry to destroy the Manikin early on.
- In the part with 5 ropes, pull the 5th rope, dropping either a doll or a manikin head, depending on whether the manikin was destroyed earlier.
- In the part where Ib can push manikin heads off tables, push off all three, instead of just the necessary one.
- When Garry needs to get a doll out of his way, kick the doll.
- When attempting to escape from the room with the dolls, run out of time (increases count by 2). Note that if the doll was kicked earlier, the timer runs faster. In old versions of the game, the correct doll was always in the top right of the room, while in newer versions the room was changed and the correct doll is randomized.
- In an extra part of a conversation between Ib and Mary that only occurs if the counter is 0, after Mary asks "What if only two of us can escape?", tell Mary you'd leave her behind.

Generally, if you're careful with the exhibit and succeed at the timed escape, he'll survive.

Building a relationship with Garry has nothing to do with his survival. If he does survive, though, building the relationship will allow you to give him your handkerchief, resulting in the Promise of Reunion ending instead of Memory's Crannies, unless you decide not to escape the world of paintings and thus get Ib All Alone. An update added another ending which can only be taken if you've given Garry the handkerchief as well.

Finally, an update added a couple endings in which Garry and Ib give up on their escape early, which technically results in Mary not killing Garry.

Comment: Ooh, I lumped them together.  This is a better answer.

Comment: Understandible. It wasn't until my second play through that I noticed there were another 5 ropes in the room Ib and Mary were in. Also, during the timed event, the doll you need to search is somewhere around the upper-right corner.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that doing the above things stop Garry from getting kicked off the deep end, however I think the doll with the key is randomized.  I once found it right by the door.  Also, though talking to Garry does nothing to change his survival chances, you learn a lot about the background of him (And slightly of of Ib's own background) from talking.  Also you could note that the more you talk to him, even if it's the same thing again and again, usually more conversation is unlocked.
To add one more thing, if Garry lives you cannot escape with Mary, or get the Ib all alone ending.

Comment: Yes, there was an update to the game which made the position of the doll containing the key randomized.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a ending where you can get ib all alone even if garry survives it's soo if mary doesn't die (i think) you can go with the fake mother when escaping with garry if you do not escape with him... you will get the ib all alone ending.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as stated there is a Garry Doom Counter, as I call it. Some things you want to do is:

- Check the 'Hug the Right Wall' advice
- Talk about the milk puzzle
- Do the rope maze
- Talk to Garry atleast 7 times in the safe room (I do over ten when I want this ending)
- Talk to Garry in the fake sunshine (I again do over ten times)
- Try to hurt as least things in the Gallery AS POSSIBLE! This includes when Garry wants to Kick the doll, wants to kick the mannequin head ect.
- In the safe room, give him back his coat that he so graciously spared you.
- Always respond to him and in a positive manner.
- When Mary runs off, check what she is doing.

If I'm correct, you should get the 'Promise of Reunion' or 'Memories Crannies' depending on how many of these you followed. To assure this, try not to do too many bad things to Garry and trust Mary. If you do, this will lead to the 'Welcome to the world of Guertena' ending. I think if Garry's counter is over 4 you have a risk of it.

I have acheived both the Memories Crannies ending and Promise of Reunion, so these facts should be correct.

Hope this helped!